# Templated function-typed static class members in C++

Tags: c++, templates, g++, language-lawyer, c++20

I have the following code, which does not compile with both g++ 8.3 and clang 9.0.0 with `-std=c++2a`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
using F = std::conditional_t<
            std::is_same_v<T, int>, int,int(T)>;
template<class T>
struct A{
    static F<double> f1; // OK
    static F<T> f2; // variable 'f2' has function type
};
int main(){
    A<double> a;
    A<double>::f1(1.3);
}
```

If I comment out this line

```
    static F<T> f2; // variable 'f2' has function type
```

it will compile (with a link error reporting undefined reference to `A<double>::f1(double)`).

Here are the questions:

1. Is `f1` *supposed to* compile?
2. If so, is `f2` supposed to compile?
3. If not, why is there such a difference in handling `f1` and `f2`?

It seems that it compiles if and only if the compilers know the type `F<T>` is a function "beforehand", but I am not sure if that is the correct behavior.

Comment: [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHR5cGVfdHJhaXRzPgoKdGVtcGxhdGU8Y2xhc3MgVD4KdXNpbmcgRiA9IHN0ZDo6Y29uZGl0aW9uYWxfdDwKICAgICAgICAgICAgc3RkOjppc19zYW1lX3Y8VCwgaW50PiwgaW50LGludChUKT47CnRlbXBsYXRlPGNsYXNzIFQ+CnN0cnVjdCBBewogICAgc3RhdGljIEY8ZG91YmxlPiBmMTsgLy8gT0sKICAgIHN0YXRpYyBGPFQ+IGYyOyAvLyB2YXJpYWJsZSAnZjInIGhhcyBmdW5jdGlvbiB0eXBlCn07CmludCBtYWluKCl7CiAgICBBPGludD4gYTsKICAgIEE8aW50Pjo6ZjEoMS4zKTsKfQ==&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0) might provide a hint

Comment: @Kerndog73 
```struct A<int> { static int f1(double); static F<int> f2; }; ```
In ```A<int>```, the type of ```f1``` is instantiated to a function, while the type of ```f2``` remained uninstantiated. (The actual type would be ```int```.) Why is this supposed to happen?

Comment: "If a function declaration acquired its function type through a dependent type without using the syntactic form of a function declarator, the program is ill-formed."

Comment: @Evg Why did the Community user vote to close this? I didn't know it could do that.

Comment: @Kerndog73, it means that OP accepted the dupe. When somebody suggests a dupe, you'll see "Yes/No" button.